# Why does the Levi-Civita connection commute with pullbacks and pushforwards?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, tensors, smooth-manifolds

If $i: M \to N$ is an embedding of Riemannian manifolds, I am trying to prove that $\nabla i^* T = i^* \nabla T$ for any covariant tensor $T$ (I use the same letter for the two Levi-Civita connections). I have managed to bring it down to proving that $\nabla _{i_* X} i_* Y = i_* \nabla _X Y$ (where it is understood that I silently extend locally the pushforwards of fields from $M$). This looks trivial, it should be the easiest part of my proof, yet I embarassedly confess that I'm blocked: how to I show this? Do I really use the injectivity of $i$ and of $i_*$?

Comment: I believe this is true. I do not have the references with me, but you could check Kobayashi & Nomizu vol. 1. The keypoint is that $i^{*} \nabla$ defines a metric, torsion-free connection on $M$. Since such a connection is unique, it must be the Levi-Civita connection on $M$. I hope this helps you a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. For example, suppose $M=\mathbb S^2$, $N=\mathbb R^3$ and $i\colon M\to N$ is the inclusion map. If you take $T$ to be a covariant tensor field on $\mathbb R^3$ with constant coefficients, then $\nabla T\equiv 0$.  But $\nabla(i^*T)$ need not be zero. For example, if $T = dx^1$, then $i^*T$ does not have constant norm and therefore cannot be parallel.

Comment: Your answer hit me hard, I'm trying to recover... It seems that a sufficient condition for my question to be answered in the affirmative is for $i(M)$ to be a totally geodesic submanifold of $N$. Are there theorems giving conditions under which a Riemann manifold could be embedded into another one (into $\Bbb R ^n$, for instance) as a totally geodesic sub manifold? (This would be a stronger version than Nash's second embedding theorem, so I believe there are not, but I still cross my fingers).

Comment: If $N$ has constant sectional curvature, then every totally geodesic submanifold has the same constant sectional curvature (this is a consequence of the Gauss equation). Thus the only Riemannian manifolds that can be embedded as totally geodesic submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$, even locally, are flat ones. (For global embeddings, there will be additional obstructions -- for example, you can't embed $\mathbb S^1\times\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb S^1\times \mathbb S^1$ as a totally geodesic submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$.)